# Puppet idempotency with rclone sync

Tags: amazon-s3, puppet, rclone

I am trying to modify some existing Puppet code that uses `rclone sync` to fetch files from an S3 bucket. The issue I'm running into is this is not exactly idempotent. From my understanding of how the existing works is that it will execute the rclone command every time, but will only update the file if the source file differs from the destination file.
This is the relevant portion of that S3 fetcher module:

```
# rclone sync the file
exec { "fetch_${file[s3_filename]}_from_${file[s3_bucket_name]}":
  user    => "bolt",
  command => "/usr/bin/rclone sync --ignore-checksum --config /usr/local/etc/rclone/${file[s3_bucket_name]}.conf ${file[s3_bucket_name]}:${file[s3_bucket_name]}/${file[s3_path]}/${file[s3_filename]} /tmp/rclone",
}
# Force file permissions
-> file { "${file[s3_filename]}":
    path           => "/tmp/rclone/${file[s3_filename]}",
    mode           => '0700',
    owner          => "bolt",
    group          => "bolt",
}
# Creates MD5 file for the checksum validation
-> file { "${file[s3_filename]}.md5":
    path           => "/tmp/rclone/${file[s3_filename]}.md5",
    content        => $md5_file_content,
    mode           => '0700',
    owner          => "bolt",
    group          => "bolt",
}
```

and this is the code I am trying to implement after-the-fact:

```
exec { "decompress_${file[s3_filename]}":
    command => "/usr/bin/tar xzf /tmp/rclone/${file[s3_filename]}",
    cwd     => "/tmp/rclone",
    creates => "/tmp/rclone/test.tar",
}
exec { "load_docker_image_${file[s3_filename]}":
  command => "/usr/bin/docker load -i /tmp/rclone/test.tar",
  require => [
    Exec["check_md5_${file[s3_filename]}"],
    Exec["decompress_${file[s3_filename]}"],
  ]
}
```

My goal is to decompress the archive that is synced from the S3 bucket and then use `docker load` on the decompressed file. The problem I'm running into is that because the `rclone sync` `exec` runs every time (it just doesnt change the file unless its different) the decompression `exec` will always run. I am trying to find a good way to only run the decompression if the compressed archive changes.

I have tried to use a mix of

```
audit          => content,
```

in the File section that forces the file permissions on the downloaded file,

and

```
subscribe => File["${file[s3_filename]}"],
refreshonly => true,
```

in the decompression `exec`, but I still cant achieve what I'm looking for. Has anyone run into a similar problem?

Comment: You can use the `file` resource with a `source` that targets a URL, and you should be able to construct a URL for the remote file location for S3. That should fix the idempotence issue here.

Comment: "*The problem I'm running into is that because the `rclone sync` `exec` runs every time [...] the decompression `exec` will always run.*" -- well no, it doesn't appear so.  The decompression `exec` has nothing in it that would make running its command conditional on anything other than whether file `/tmp/rclone/test.tar` already exists.  Maybe you're cleaning out that file between or during runs?  Or maybe the Exec doesn't really create that file? Either of those would explain the decompression running every time.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard I saw this as a potential method, but I didnt see a great way to do that if the bucket requires authentication. I've done it with Curl and the AWSCLI previously but I'm not sure how those would apply to this.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for the explanation. I'll do some more specific testing, and look into other ways to pull this file from the bucket in the meantime.